# Display a pattern lock activity before opening an app

Tags: java, android

I work in android studio with java,
i have a pattern lock activity and a list of installed apps and i want when i select an app the pattern lock activity appear before the this app launch

So how I can display the pattern screen before opening the selected apps please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need :

**First add this dependency to dependencies :**

```
com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0
```

**Then add PatternLockView to your XML file :**

```
<com.andrognito.patternlockview.PatternLockView
    android:id="@+id/mypatternlockview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
```

**Then import these to your pattern activity :**

```
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.PatternLockView;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.utils.*;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.listener.*;
```

**Then add the PatternLockView :**

```
private PatternLockView mypatternlockview;
```

**Then add this to the onCreate void :**

```
mypatternlockview = (PatternLockView) findViewById(R.id.mypatternlockview);
mypatternlockview.addPatternLockListener(new PatternLockViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStarted() {
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onProgress(List<PatternLockView.Dot> _pattern) {
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onComplete(List<PatternLockView.Dot> _pattern) {
            if (PatternLockUtils.patternToString(mypatternlockview, _pattern).equals(savedPattern)) {
                //The pattern is correct, you can pass
                mypatternlockview.setViewMode(PatternLockView.PatternViewMode.CORRECT);
                //Launch the app
            }
            else {
                //The pattern is incorrect, you can't pass
                mypatternlockview.setViewMode(PatternLockView.PatternViewMode.WRONG);
                mypatternlockview.clearPattern();
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onCleared() {
            
        }
    });
}
```

`savedPattern` is a `String` that stores the saved pattern

When the user completes drawing the pattern the application checks if the enterd pattern matches the saved pattern

you can save a pattern using another PatternLockView in another activity & SharedPreferences, if you want to know how to do that just ask me in the chat